# Having Problems With Metal Material

Tags: texturing

I am trying to apply [this] material
[image]

(https://www.poliigon.com/texture/metal-spotty-discoloration-001)

to a rectangle by using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NUl3GvT92T8) tutorial.

But when I tried to to put the respective materials into blender, it ended up looking like chocolate mess.

[image: this]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxBbk.jpg

For reference, I unwrapped the object, than I applied all of the materials as per the video, since the materials were set up the same way. Any help?

Comment: What does it look like outside of edit mode when it isn't highlighted orange? Also you may want to check your scene lighting. Particularly with reflective materials, lighting plays a bit part in how they look.

Comment: perhaps share your file with packed images textures, or at least show a screenshot of your node editor

Comment: Check if you have applied Image Texture not to Diffuse Material but Glossy BSDF. If its Glossy BSDF that it is correct.

Comment: Ah, it appears I just used the wrong materials for each part.